# Register Hazelcast Cluster instances on Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot service in which I've started an HazelCast instance.

```
@Bean
public Config config(){
    return new Config();

}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config config){
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
}
```

Now, I want to register my HazelCast instances in Eureka so that my HC clients can retrieve HC cluster instances dynamically.

HazelCast plugin page point me to the [eureka plugin](https://github.com/hazelcast-incubator/eurekast-one) but this one is from 2015 and contains a lot of deprecated code recommending me to use EurekaModule and DI.

Does someone have an example?

Comment: review Neil's answer and kindly mark it as solved, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-eureka-partition-groups
Should do what you need

Comment: is this the preferred way (in 2020) of doing things over the eureka-one-plugin?

Comment: The Spring Boot demo is an old demo that was recently refeshed for Hazelcast 4. But the `hazelcast-eureka-one` is the better way if you can use it.